Probability that of a plurality vote is correct with multiple options
There are many questions 1, 2, 3 as well as Condorcet's jury theorem that address finding the probability that a majority vote over a set of responses is correct when responses are generated by $k$ independent participants that each has some prescribed probability of responding correctly.
I'm interested in the generalization where there are multiple responses to choose from and only one is correct.
Suppose we have $k$ identical participants that choose between $n$ options.
They choose the correct options w.p. $p$ and randomly from the other $n-1$ incorrect options w.p. $(1-p)/(n-1)$. Can we write down or at least solve for a particular instance of $n$, $p$ and $k$ the probability that the correct response makes up the plurality? I suspect that only approximate solutions can be written down for large $k$ but would be happy to be proven wrong!
Another option would be to frame this in the language of an exact probabilistic inference engine like psi solver for some values $n$, $p$ and $k$.

Edit: In Mathematica, I can compute some instances using
PluralityCorrect[n_, k_, p_] := 
 Probability[
  And @@ Table[Subscript[a, 1] > Subscript[a, j], {j, 2, n}], 
  Table[Subscript[a, i], {i, n}] \[Distributed] 
   MultinomialDistribution[k, 
    Join[{p}, (1 - p) ConstantArray[1, n - 1]/(n - 1)]]]

PluralityCorrect[5, 5, p] -> 1/4 p^2 (15 - 5 p - 15 p^2 + 9 p^3)
PluralityCorrect[10, 10, 1/2] -> 27427297/30233088



the number of correct responses follows $Bin(k,p)$

When you say majority, do you mean "more than half" or "more than any other individual selection gets" (sometimes called plurality)?

Yes I mean more than any other individual selection gets

The number of votes is going to be: 1. Binomial in the correct response. 2. Conditionally mutinomial in the other categories (with n = the number of votes that are incorrect). If you want to know when the correct answer has a plurality, you need to compare the number of correct reponses to the max of a multinomial. I don't think that's explicit, but perhaps that could be approximated with the max of a correlated multivariate Gaussian, or perhaps something better than that. Sampling would be appropriate too.

@GuillaumeDehaene thanks for the response I figured there may be some sort of recurrence to compute coefficients on the polynomials in p as a function of n and k so I can at least solve it exactly for some cases as I've shown can be done with Mathematica.

Let the number of correct answers be $X\sim Bin(k, p)$. $X$ is binomially distributed because each answer is independent with the same probability $p$ of being correct, and there are $k$ answers. For your question, which incorrect answer is chosen is irrelevant.
So for a weak majority we want to calculate $P(X \ge \frac12 k)$
$$= \sum_{r=\lceil \frac12 k \rceil}^{k} \binom{k}{r} p^r (1-p)^{k-r}$$
For a strict majority we use $\lfloor \frac12 k \rfloor + 1$.

Im interested in the case where the count of correct votes is more than any other incorrect selection gets. As pointed out in the comments this should be plurality not majority.
